# Probability of a plant dying when it is dependent on the probability of it being watered.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

You ask a neighbor to water a sickly plant while you are on vacation. Without water the plant will die with probability 0.85. With water it will die with probability 0.5. You are 81 % certain the neighbor will remember to water the plant. I need to find the probability that the plant will die. I also need to find the probability that the neighbor forgot to water the plant if the plant is dead when I come back.

Comment: The first problem is pretty straightforward. There are two ways that the plant can die: (1) the neighbor doesn’t water it, and (2) the neighbor waters it, but it dies anyway. What’s the probability of (1)? Of (2)?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Use definitions of conditional probability to write what you need in terms of what you know:
\begin{align*}
P(\text{plant dies}) &= P(\text{neighbor remembers AND plant dies}) + P(\text{neighbor forgets AND plant dies})\\
&=P(\text{neighbor remembers}) \cdot P(\text{plant dies} \mid \text{neighbor remembers}) \\&\quad+ P(\text{neighbor forgets}) \cdot P(\text{plant dies} \mid \text{neighbor forgets}) \end{align*}

Use Bayes's rule and the probability that you found in the previous part:
\begin{align*}
P(\text{neighbor forgets} \mid \text{plant dead}) &= \frac{P(\text{neighbor forgets AND plant dies})}{P(\text{plant dies})}\\
&= \frac{P(\text{plant dies} \mid \text{neighbor forgets}) \cdot P(\text{neighbor forgets})}{P(\text{plant dies})}
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that the first part is exactly what Brian M. Scott suggested in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with conditional probabilities, i.e. let the event that the plant is watered be $W$ and that it dies $D$.  Then $P(D|\bar{W}) = 0.85$, $P(D|W)=0.5$.  Also $P(W)=0.81$ so that

$$P(D) = P(D|W) P(W) + P(D|\bar{W}) P(\bar{W}) = (0.5)(0.81)+(0.85)(0.19) = 0.5665$$

The probability that the neighbor forgot to water is given by Bayes' theirem:

$$P(\bar{W}|D) = \frac{P(\bar{W} \cap D)}{P(D)}$$

or

$$P(\bar{W}|D) = \frac{P(D|\bar{W}) P(\bar{W})}{ P(D|W) P(W) + P(D|\bar{W}) P(\bar{W})} = \frac{(0.85)(0.19)}{0.5665}\approx 0.285$$